# Find the indicies of common tuples in two list of tuples without loop in Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, tuples, indices

How can one find the indexes of the common tuples in two list of tuples?

```
tuplelist1 = [("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f"), ("g","h")]
tuplelist2 = [("c","d"),("e","f")]
```

So the indices in tuplelist1 that are common with tupplelist2 are indices 1 and 2.

Is there a way to figure this out without a loop? Is there a way to do this with sets or list comprehension, for instance?

Thanks!

Comment: You realize that list comprehension is a loop... right?

Comment: Make `tuplelist2` a set if you have a lof of data to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a list comprehension, you could do

```
indices_of_shared = [index for (index, pair) in enumerate(tuplelist1) if pair in tuplelist2]
```

Comment: Does this just list the index of list 1 if it exists in list 2? Perhaps `if pair == tupleList2[index]`?

Comment: Yes, this just tests for the existence of the tuple in the other list, not that it appears at the same index. Your code should work if you require it to appear at the same index.